# How to implement interface Serializable in scala?

Tags: scala

I have scala class like:

```
@Entity("users")
class User(@Required val cid: String, val isAdmin: Boolean = false, @Required val dateJoined: Date = new Date() ) {
  @Id var id: ObjectId = _



    @Reference
  val foos = new ArrayList[Foo]

    }
```

If it was a Java class I would simply put implements java.io.Serializable but this does not work in scala. Also is foos as declared above is private or public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

scala 2.9.x also have an interface named Serializable, you may extends or mixin this. before 2.9.x the @serializable is the only choice.

Comment: I'm using scala 2.10 how can implements Serializable? I tried with Serializable but doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: @GavinNiu Are you looking for `class FooBar with Serializeable`?

Answer (score 4):

[How do I use a @serializable scala object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442171/how-do-i-use-a-serializable-scala-object)

foos is public unless marked otherwise

Answer (score 2):

You can add Serialized annotation on your Scala Class (at JPA Entity for example):

> Because Serializable is a trait, you can mix it into a class, even if
>   your class already extends another class:

```
@SerialVersionUID(114L)
class Employee extends Person with Serializable ...
```

Se more details at this link:
https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/scala-cookbook/9781449340292/ch12s08.html

Comment: An example of my Entity (JPA) class writed in scala:

Answer (score 0):

An example of my Entity (JPA) class writed in scala, using Serialized properties:

```
import javax.persistence._

import scala.beans.BeanProperty
import java.util.Date

@SerialVersionUID(1234110L)
@Entity
@Table(name = "sport_token")
class Token() extends Serializable {

  @Id
  @SequenceGenerator(name="SPORT_TOKEN_SEQ",catalog="ESPORTES" , sequenceName="SPORT_TOKEN_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE , generator="SPORT_TOKEN_SEQ")
  @BeanProperty
  var id: Int = _

  @BeanProperty
  @Column(name="token")
  var token: String = _

  @BeanProperty
  @Column(name="active")
  var active: Int = _

}
```