# Serialization of Scala Objects

Tags: java, scala, serialization

I am following the [basic example of scala object serialization](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-serialization-in-scala-serializable-trait).  However, when running the below unit test

```
package mytest

import java.io.{ByteArrayOutputStream, ObjectOutputStream}

import org.scalatest.{Matchers, WordSpec}

class BasicSerializationSpec extends WordSpec with Matchers {

  @SerialVersionUID(123L)
  class TestRecord(var content: String) extends Serializable {
    override def toString = s"TestRecord($content)"
  }

  "A TestRecord" should {
    "be serializable" in {
      val oo = new ObjectOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream())

      val tr = new TestRecord("42")

      oo.writeObject(tr)

      oo.close
    }
  }
}
```

I get an Exception:

> org.scalatest.Assertions$AssertionsHelper
>   java.io.NotSerializableException: 
>         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
>         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
>         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
>         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
>         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
>         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
>         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
>         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
>         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
>         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
>         at mytest.BasicSerializationSpec.$anonfun$new$2(BasicSerializationSpec.scala:20)

I have tried to explicitly set the type

```
val tr : java.io.Serializable = new TestRecord("42")
```

But still no luck.

**How do I properly serialize a scala object to a java ObjectOutputStream**?

This is not a duplication of [other stack answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551694/how-to-implement-interface-serializable-in-scala) because I am clearly extending `Serializable` with my class declaration.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Serializing inner classes is a minefield in both Java and Scala, but provided that in your real code there are no references to `BasicSerializationSpec`'s members in `TestRecord`, you should be able to make this work by adding a `final` modifier to the inner class definition:

```
final class TestRecord(var content: String) extends Serializable {
```

In real code you're unlikely to be testing classes that you define inside your test class, but you may run into similar situations when testing inner classes.